# How do I split a dataframe by a repeating index and enumerate?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
    0 1 2
#   A B C
1   D E F
2   G H I
#   J K L
1   M N O
2   P Q R
3   S T U
```

The index has a repeating 'delimiter', namely #. I am seeking an efficient way to transform this to the following:

```
    0 1 2 3
#   A B C 1
1   D E F 1
2   G H I 1
#   J K L 2
1   M N O 2
2   P Q R 2
3   S T U 2
```

I would like a new column (3) which is splitting by the # symbol in the rows and enumerating the chunks. This is for an NLP application and the dataset I am working with can be found here for context: https://sites.google.com/site/germeval2014ner/data.

By the way, I know I can do this with a simple iteration, but I am wondering if there is vectorized format or a split capability I am not aware of.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
df['new_col'] = (df.index == '#').cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   1  2  3  new_col
0                  
#  A  B  C        1
1  D  E  F        1
2  G  H  I        1
#  J  K  L        2
1  M  N  O        2
2  P  Q  R        2
3  S  T  U        2
```

Comment: Very useful solution! one can replace '#' with wathever suits for a specific case. In my case I had a pattern in the index with numbers from 0 to 1000 and I used the int 0 to count the repeating pattern